How do i import obj models in python and be able to view them in mesh form
Although i know i can do this already using libraries like vedo, what i want is to be able to view the individual vertices of the model (kind of like the edit mode in blender) and be able to assign labels to certain parts of the model. I am having a hard time even being able to find a direction to proceed in with if this is even possible in the first place or not, was hoping someone here could guide me.
I have tried importing the models using vedo and pyvista (which works), but could not figure how i can label individual parts of the model.

what "model" do you mean? What file format do you mean? You have to describe all details  in question (not in comments) because we can't read in your mind.

if you made something with pyvista then you could show minimal working code - so maybe we could use it to run it and test some ideas or maybe to create some solution. And it would need link to some example object which we could use in program

hey @furas , Im sorry for the late reply coz i got my initial problem figured out (i just didnt look deep enough into pyvista documentation). I was wondering if you could help me out on another issue regarding pyvista.

if you have new problem then create new question on new page - and describe all details. Later you may add comment with @furas and Stackoveflow will send be message. But I'm not expect in pyvista.
